# How to get multiple Parallax images working on iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, parallax

I am having a hard time trying to get multiple parallax images to work on iOS for this [website](https://justintara.com/). I understand that `background-attachement: fixed` does not render in iOS so I tried the examples [here](https://codepen.io/Everybodyknows/pen/YzzQMpG) and [here](https://codepen.io/Everybodyknows/pen/abbyLOZ) but neither of them are really the solution I need.

CSS:

```
.parallax1 {
  background-image: url("images/index/practitioners.png");
  height: 35vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.parallax2 {
  background-image: url("images/index/consumers.png");
  height: 35vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.parallax3 {
  background-image: url("images/index/network.png");
  height: 35vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="practitioners.html" class="paralink"><div class="parallax1"></div></a>
   <div align="center">
     <p class="pagehead" style="color: #000; width: 50%;">Learn the philosophy and products CArx uses to heal.</p>
   </div>
    
<a href="consumers.html" class="paralink"><div class="parallax2"></div></a>
   <div align="center">
     <p class="pagehead" style="color: #000; width: 50%;">Information about the Cellular Alchemy Elite program and transform your home into an oasis of wellness and vitality with the latest scientific innovations in health validated for their efficacy.</p>
</div>

<a href="network.html" class="paralink"><div class="parallax3"></div></a>
   <div align="center">
     <p class="pagehead" style="color: #000; width: 50%;">See who CArx partners with to bring whole body wellness to life.</p>
</div>
```

I tried putting them into divs with `position: fixed` attributes but that's not really gong to work with more than 1 image. I need multiple parallax images.

Answer (score 0):

the codes that you have attached produces parallax scrolling!!! but if you don't see the effect accurately then do increase the height of your images or sections respectively in which you wanna produce a parallax effect.

For further problems do mail me at mulla786mohammedumar@yahoo.com